# Why does Docker Desktop uninstall hang?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm trying to uninstall Docker Desktop (it doesn't launch) so that i can reinstall it again, I have tried updating it , It keeps telling me that i have the latest Docker Desktop

[image: Gui of docker desktop state]

Comment: This issue still exists in 2023 June !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Win + R
- services.msc
- Stop Docker Desktop Service
- Uninstall Docker

See: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7489#issuecomment-757835075

Answer (score 17):

I Found the solution, and of course it involves the Windows Registry.

There was a key in Windows Registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall called “Docker Desktop.”

I deleted it and all of its sub-keys and the Docker installation then went to completion.

Comment: In my case the uninstall process broke after this

Comment: In my case i could not uninstall it from appwiz after that.

Comment: I guess, SHDR and @RunTheGauntlet - you must first uninstall the app from windows uninstaller and then delete the above key in registry. Restart the windows and reinstall the docker.

Answer (score 6):

Delete the contents of C:\Program Files\Docker and download a fresh Docker installer

Comment: I tried that but Windows thinks the installation is already up to date, so it does nothing. If there's a manual way to uninstall, I need to find it.

Comment: @user3120861 It works. After it shows that try uninstalling again. Then you can use Docker installer, if required.

Comment: Had to do this in conjunction with the registry change suggested by @manoj kumar

Answer (score 4):

Before you uninstall ensure you stop Docker Desktop Service on windows Service manager.
The steps are as follows:

- Hit the Windows Key then type `Services`
- Select `Run as administrator`
- Look for Docker Desktop Service -> Right click -> Stop
- Proceed with normal uninstall of the Docker Desktop from the programs and features list.

*Happy Uninstall*

Answer (score 4):

Open cmd prompt and run this command:

`"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" uninstall`

This worked for me. Previously it was hanging on "Removing VM and images".

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, except that the uninstaller was unable to delete the directory "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker" because that was the directory that cmd.exe was currently in.  To get around that, I think it's better to navigate to "C:\Program Files" then run "Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" uninstall

Comment: I edited the answer and simplified it even further. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Closed the window, downloaded a new version from the official website, then installed again. When asked if I wanted to replace the old version with the new one, I answered "Yes" and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

The uninstaller requires Hyper-V to be installed, when having used that.
One has to uninstall Docker Desktop first and then can uninstall Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solved it for me. Turns out it can [fail to uninstall](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13799) if you use a RAMDisk for your temp folder.

Apparently the same issue [affects updates too](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13914).

Answer (score -2):

Try to restart your PC. Then try to uninstall again.

Answer (score -8):

I had the same problem on my working laptop and I had to manually delete all the regestry keys (win + r, then type in regedit) and the whole folder in C:\Program Files.
After that I had no issues and Docker Desktop completely disappeared in Apps

Comment: Delete all `C:\Program Files` is a little too much ? Why don't find the exact folder that is not fine instead of breaking lot of program for docker fix ? Another answer talk about `C:\Program Files\Docker` and a second one talk about regedit too, so it's seems to be a duplicate ?